# grep in ubuntu for text occurrence

Tags: grep

I currently have a text file which contains the following lines of text in it. I need to use grep to display the number of lines the word `test` appears in the file for different scenario. Below are some things I have tried, but the output is wrong. I am pretty new to using grep, so hope someone could assist to advice where I have done wrong.

**test.txt:**

```
this is some testing for my own test purpose.

testing testing testing 1 2 3 test

test-case 1 is for delete purpose

tester’s is coming to test out the new devices

Tester test 3 test case
```

**Scenario 1:**

Report on how many lines in the text file test contain the case-sensitive word “test”. It should not include count of word that is a substring of another word. E.g testing, tester’s, test-case

Ans: `grep “\btest\b” test | wc -l`

**Scenario 2:**

Report on how many times the case-sensitive word “test” appears in the text file test (within other words is ok)

Ans: `grep –o “test” test | wc -w`

**Scenario 3:**

Report on how many times the word “test” appears in the last 2 lines of the text file test

Ans: `tail –n 2 test | grep –o “\btest\b” | wc -w`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following :

Scenario 1:

```
$ grep -i -c "[^a-z]test[^a-z]" test.txt
```

Scenario 2:

```
$ grep –o “test” test.txt | wc -l
```

Scenario 3:

```
$ tail -2 test.txt | grep -o "[^a-z]test[^a-z]" | wc -l
```